# How to send a message to several processes through the same pipe? (C language)

Tags: c, pipe, ipc

PROJECT:

The forecast station send the data to the control tower which dispatches the data to all aircrafts identified by is PID (unknown number of plane, who may enter or leave the zone controlled by the control tower ).

[image: Project Diagram]

CURRENTLY:

The Forecast sends the data to the Control Tower (which is listening on the pipe) then sends the data to one plane (the last connected) and resends the data if we change the forecast by resend new info to the control tower.

PROBLEM:

How to make the control tower sends the forecast to all connected plane:

1. if one new plane connects himself to the control tower
2. if new forecast --> resend data to all the connected airplanes

   ```
   // Librairies de fonction.
   #include "Extends.h"

   // fifo_s représente le chemin d'accès a la fifo du controltower.
   const char fifo_s[] = "Fifo_Server";
   // fifo_p représente le chemin d'accès a la fifo des Planes
   const char fifo_p[] = "Fifo_Planes";

   // Structure des données qui seront reçues puis envoyées.
   typedef struct {
   char data[1000];
   int pid;
   } T_Data;

   // Prototype de la fonction STOP semblable a un getchar() mais sans     attente.
   int STOP();

   /*******************************/
   // Fonction main sans arguments.
   int main() {
   int serv = 0, nbOct = 0, dest = 0;
   char fifo_d[1000];
   T_Data controltower;
   system("clear");
   printf("(1) Création des FIFOS\n");

   // Creation de la fifo de transfert du controltower (fifo_controltower).
   // Et des fifos tampons entre le controltower et les programmes destinataires.
   if ((mkfifo(fifo_s, 0666) < 0) ||
       (mkfifo(fifo_p, 0666) < 0)) {
       if (errno != EEXIST) {
           printf("-->FIFO déjà existante!\n");
           exit(EEXIST);
       }
       else {
           printf("-->Impossible de créer la FIFO!\n");
           exit(2);
       }
   }
   printf("(1-1) Bonne creation des fifos!\n");

   // Ouverture de la fifo du controltower en mode lecture et ecriture.
   // serv reçoit le descripteur de cette fifo.
   serv = open(fifo_s, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
   printf("(2) Ouverture de la FIFO de transfert\n");
   if (serv > 0) {
       printf("(2-1) FIFO correctement ouverte!\n");
   }
   printf("(3) Attente des information Météos !\n");
   printf("================================================================\n");

   // Tant que la fonction STOP ne renvoi pas 1.
   while (STOP() == 0) {
       // Lecture des informations dans la fifo de transfert du controltower.
       if ((nbOct = read(serv, &controltower, sizeof(T_Data))) != -1) {
           printf("(4) Lecture de %d octets effectuée dans la FIFO de transfert\n", nbOct);
           printf("================================================================\n");
           //printf ("(5) Données Météo : %s\n",controltower.data);
           printf("(5) Envoi des données vers les avions...\n");


           // Ouverture de la fifo tampon du destinataire en mode ecriture
           dest = open(fifo_p, O_WRONLY);
           // Ecriture des informations récupérées dans la fifo controltower dans la fifo tampon du destinataire.

           write(dest, controltower.data, sizeof(T_Data));

           printf("Données Envoyée!");

           printf("Tapez 'S' pour terminer le controltower !\n");
           printf("================================================================\n");
       }

       else {
           sleep(1);
       }
   }

   printf("\n================================================================\n");
   printf("Fermeture du controltower\n");
   printf("================================================================\n");
   // Delinkage et destruction des fifos controltower et tampon destinataires.
   if ((-1 == unlink(fifo_s)) ||
       (-1 == unlink(fifo_p))) {
       perror("unlink Erreur");
   }
   // Fermeture de la fifo tampon utlisée.
   close(dest);
   // Fermeture de la fifo tampon.
   close(serv);
   printf("Effacement de la console dans 3secondes!\n");
   sleep(3);
   system("clear");
   return (0);
   }
   ```

Thanks in advance...

NB: Excuse me if I've made some mistakes... I'm doing my best but it's not my first language...

Comment: Set up a separate pipe to each plane on connection? Dispatch the incoming forecast to each existing pipe, but the receiving one? Perhaps sent the last forecast received the moment a newly connected plane had its pipe set up.

Comment: Hi, yeah I thought about it... But my teacher don't want " sequential " work (although everything is sequential) but only one pipe on which the applications has accumulated one after the other the request and execute them with FIFO or something like that...

Comment: If all planes (processes) should read from the same pipe, you a.) need write the forecast to the pipe as often as there are planes and b.) make sure only one plane at a time reads a full forecast from the pipe.

Comment: I 've made an endless loop (while(1){write(dest, controltower.data, sizeof(T_Data));}) for the Control tower to send the forecast at all time... this allow x number of planes to receive the forecast and it works but it does not allow me to change the forecast anymore... And I'm not shure how the planes read the forecast it is open pipe in  NONBLOCK mode (env = open(fifo_p,O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK);)  but I think it is still a ramdom reading...

Comment: If available for the implementation you are using, check for what `O_DIRECT` does on a pipe (see: `man pipe` for details).

Comment: I will thx a lot for your help... I'll keep you informed

Comment: I've found out that PIPE is good to use when you have one client (plane)... If you have more than one destination, it is better to use socket()

Comment: And would make using sockets instead of pipes changes the way to implement the communications requirements?

Comment: Having multiple client read from the same socket raises the same issues as if they were reading from the same pipe.

Answer (score 1):

> I've found out that PIPE is good to use when you have one client
>   (plane)... If you have more than one destination, it is better to use
>   socket()

Here's a version of sending data using `socket()` etc.:

```
        dest = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if (dest == -1) return perror("socket"), 1;
        // address the port 9163 (chosen arbitrarily)
        struct sockaddr_in a = { AF_INET, htons(9163), htonl(0x7fffffff) };
        const int true = 1;
        setsockopt(dest, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &true, sizeof true);
        sendto(dest, &controltower, nbOct, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&a, sizeof a);
        close(dest);
```

If `socat` is available, you can simulate any plane with:

```
socat UDP-RECV:9163,reuseaddr 1
```